# How to have periodical repetition of customized pulse waveform in LT Spice?

Tags: switches, ltspice, simulation, control, pwl

I have a customized Pulse pattern and I would like to have it in repetition. Does anyone know how we can establish that in LT spice?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PWL sources can be repeated either a set number of times:

```
PWL REPEAT FOR 7 (file=pwl_data.txt) ENDREPEAT
```

or forever:

```
PWL REPEAT FOREVER (file=pwl_data.txt) ENDREPEAT
```

Source: http://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=Undocumented_LTspice

Comment: Perfect! The link also helps a lot.

Comment: @Durgaprasad One note that is not immediately seen: if the sequence needs to be repeated a lot of times, it may take a while to computate all the points. This is because PWL points are known beforehand, so extending the timescale by N is done by linearly interpolating *all* the points. Depending on how large N is, it can take up quite a bit to compute everything. This is why it's better to use `repeat forever`, because LTspice seems to determine the length of the sequence relative to the total simulation time, and no more. It just might be cheaper. Or not, but probably will be. YMMV.

Comment: Yes, I did use the FOREVER function an it takes the endpoint as our simulation stop time. This is fast and hassle-free.